# Iterating through an array and deleting the ith character the printing the array

Tags: c

I am trying to loop through a word and delete the ith character of the word and then print out the word, but I end up getting Abort Trap 6. Here is my code....

```
 int main(){

    int i;
    char arr[] = "Tenesssee";
    char temp[21];

    strcpy(temp, arr);

    for (i = 0; i <strlen(temp); i++){
        strcpy(&temp[i], &temp[i + 1]);
        printf("%s", temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please ask a sensible question in the title.

Comment: `strcpy()`'s source and destination shouldn't overlap, and `strcpy()` copies a null-terminated string not a single `char`.

Comment: As far as I can see, you are attempting not to just remove an unspecified `i`th character, but *every* character.

Answer (score 0):

You have done some mistakes. You're question is somewhat ambiguous. One of these do will do what you want. The first deletes the element and updates the array, the second only deletes the element.

```
void removeElemAndUpdate(char** word, int i ){
   char* arr = *word;
   printf("Length of word %d \n",strlen(arr));
   if(i==0){
      char* newarr =calloc(strlen(arr),1);
      strcpy(newarr,&arr[1]);
      printf("%s\n",newarr); 
      free(arr);
      *word=newarr;
   }else if(i>=strlen(arr)){
      printf("%d is outside the array bounds\n",i);
   }else{
      char* start = calloc(strlen(arr),1);
      char* end   = calloc(strlen(arr)-i + 1,1); 
      strncpy(start,arr,i);
      strcpy(end, &arr[i+1]);
      strcat(start,end);
      free(arr);
      printf("%s\n",start);
      free(end);
      *word=start;
   }

}

void removeElem(char* arr,int i){
   if(i==0){
      char* newarr =calloc(strlen(arr),1);
      strcpy(newarr,&arr[1]);
      printf("%s\n",newarr); 
      free(newarr);
   }else if(i>=strlen(arr)){
      printf("%d is outside the array bounds\n",i);
   }else{
      char* start = calloc(strlen(arr),1);
      char* end   = calloc(strlen(arr)-i + 1,1); 
      strncpy(start,arr,i);
      strcpy(end, &arr[i+1]);
      strcat(start,end);
      printf("%s\n",start);
      free(end);
      free(start);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps